# django when select format time column

Tags: django, select, model

django model JobError(id int pk, create_time datetime[2017-07-24 00:00:14])
sql below：

```
SELECT time_format,count(id) as total
from (SELECT
id,
date_format(create_time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') AS time_format
FROM monitor_job_error
WHERE create_time > '2017-7-24')as tab
GROUP BY time_format
```

I want use django orm now, how can i do when selct create_time do date_format.

```
JobError.objects.filter(create_time__gte=(datetime.now()-relativedelta(hours=15))).order_by('create_time').values('create_time').annotate(total=Count('id'))`
```

guys, please help. thanks!:)

Comment: Where do you show it (templates)?

Comment: No, In jQuery Flot  chart

Comment: this is a client side operation, Do this with javascript or jquery plugins (moment.js)

Comment: Yes,  django + jQuery.js + jQuery.flot.js